# Saving cookies in java HashMap

Tags: java, cookies, hashmap, jsoup

I am getting a logging into a webpage using JSOUP and recording the cookie into a HashMap, which is then saved into a database as plain text. When accessing the website, I retrieve the cookie from the database, parse it, and pass it back to the website.

All this has been working just fine.

However the site have now added an additional cookie which contains several `,` symbols. This means when I parse the cookie I don't know which is a separator anymore.

Previous cookie, example:

```
ASP.NET_SessionId=lflgkjo598jgzp4e5iygtpj5smg94, username=Andrew5465
```

New cookie, example contains , symbols:

```
ASP.NET_SessionId=lflgkjo598jgzp4e5iygtpj5smg94, username=Andrew5465, logindate=01,Jan,2017
```

Is there a way to change the separator in a HashMap from , to a # or something else?

If not, how else can I fix this issue?

Comment: *Is there a way to change the separator in a HashMap?*: what does that mean?

Comment: Updated with more info

Comment: But didn't answer my question.

Comment: Maybe don't store Map as text but as bytes, or use textual format which will allow you to parse it back from text easily, like JSON.

Comment: Is there no easier way to escape the , symbol before saving it?

Comment: You could create your own escaping mechanism, but what is the point of other parsers already handled it? With gson you could for instance use `String json = gson.toJson(cookies);` to create String representation of your cookies map, and with `Map<String,String> cookiesFromDB = gson.fromJson(jsonFromDB, new TypeToken<Map<String,String>>(){}.getType());` you can change it back to your cookie map. It is quite easy IMO.